# Wait for new page to load Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, performance, sleep, webdriverwait

From the following website:

URL: https://www.italotreno.it/it/destinazioni-orari/orari-treni

when updating search results (selecting another element of the drop down menu therefore searching for results) I need to wait for the page to load, but can't quite use `ExplicitWait` as it won't wait for elements to appear because it detects the same elements from the previous results.
Seems to work with `sleep()` but it's not very efficient, as the loading time depends on the results numerosity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe find the previous elements, assign them to a variable, and wait for them to become *stale* before waiting for the new elements?

Comment: Does a new element get loaded with the dropdown? If so you could try: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ID")))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! May have solved it by finding the loading bar element and explicitly waiting for it to become _stale_.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.